# How to properly refer to module's map value?

Tags: module, terraform, reference, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to deploy cluster to GKE using Terraform and use map's value while doing that.
When referencing to cluster module's key, the values are not used and I am asked for input.

Here are my configs for gke_cluster module:

*terraform/modules/gke_cluster/main.tf*:

```
variable "node_pool_overwrites" {
  description = "Overwritten node pool configurations for specific clusters"
  type        = map(any)
  default     = {}
}
resource "google_container_cluster" "gke_cluster" {
  name     = var.name
  location = var.location

  initial_node_count       = 1
  remove_default_node_pool = true

  dynamic "node_pool" {
    for_each = merge(
      lookup(var.default_node_pool_configs),
      var.node_pool_overwrites
    )

    content {
      name       = node_pool.key
      node_count = node_pool.value.count

      node_config {
        machine_type = node_pool.value.hw
        image_type   = "COS"
        labels = {
          type     = node_pool.key
          name     = var.name
          location = var.location
        }

        // Additional config for specialized node pools
        dynamic "taint" {
          for_each = node_pool.key == "proxy" || node_pool.key == "proxyspot" ? [1] : []

          content {
            key    = "dedicated"
            value  = "proxy"
            effect = "NO_EXECUTE"
          }
        }
      }

      autoscaling {
        min_node_count = node_pool.value.min
        max_node_count = node_pool.value.max
      }

      management {
        auto_upgrade = true
        auto_repair  = true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

*terraform/modules/gke_cluster/outputs.tf*:

```
output "endpoint" {
  description = "The endpoint of the GKE cluster."
  value       = google_container_cluster.gke_cluster.endpoint
}

output "name" {
  description = "The name of the GKE cluster."
  value       = google_container_cluster.gke_cluster.name
}

output "location" {
  description = "The location of the GKE cluster."
  value       = google_container_cluster.gke_cluster.location
}
```

*terraform/modules/gke_cluster/variables.tf*:

```
variable "name" {
  description = "The name of the GKE cluster."
  type        = string
}

variable "location" {
  description = "The location to host the GKE cluster."
  type        = string
}

variable "node_pools" {
  description = "A map of node pool configurations."
  type        = map(any)
}

variable "default_node_pool_configs" {
  description = "Default node pool configurations for GKE clusters"
  type        = map(any)
  default = {
    "pop2" = {
      default = {
        hw           = "custom-2-4096"
        disk         = "pd-standard"
        disk_size_gb = 15
        count        = 2
        min          = 0
        max          = 0
      },
      proxy = {
        hw           = "highcpu-4"
        disk         = "pd-standard"
        disk_size_gb = 15
        count        = 0
        min          = 0
        max          = 20
      },
      proxyspot = {
        hw           = "highcpu-4"
        disk         = "pd-standard"
        disk_size_gb = 15
        count        = 1
        min          = 0
        max          = 20
      }
    },
    "pop4" = {
      default = {
        hw           = "highcpu-4"
        disk         = "pd-standard"
        disk_size_gb = 15
        count        = 2
        min          = 0
        max          = 0
      },
      proxy = {
        hw           = "highcpu-4"
        disk         = "pd-standard"
        disk_size_gb = 50
        count        = 0
        min          = 0
        max          = 20
      },
      proxyspot = {
        hw           = "highcpu-4"
        disk         = "pd-standard"
        disk_size_gb = 15
        count        = 1
        min          = 0
        max          = 20
      }
    },
    "pop4xl" = {
      default = {
        hw           = "highcpu-4"
        disk         = "pd-standard"
        disk_size_gb = 100
        count        = 2
        min          = 0
        max          = 0
      },
      proxy = {
        hw           = "highcpu-8"
        disk         = "pd-standard"
        disk_size_gb = 50
        count        = 0
        min          = 0
        max          = 20
      },
      proxyspot = {
        hw           = "highcpu-8"
        disk         = "pd-standard"
        disk_size_gb = 15
        count        = 1
        min          = 0
        max          = 20
      }
    },
    "pop6xl" = {
      default = {
        hw           = "custom-6-8192"
        disk         = "pd-standard"
        disk_size_gb = 15
        count        = 2
        min          = 0
        max          = 0
      },
      proxy = {
        hw           = "highcpu-8"
        disk         = "pd-standard"
        disk_size_gb = 15
        count        = 0
        min          = 0
        max          = 20
      },
      proxyspot = {
        hw           = "highcpu-8"
        disk         = "pd-standard"
        disk_size_gb = 15
        count        = 1
        min          = 0
        max          = 20
      }
    },
    "pop8" = {
      default = {
        hw           = "highcpu-8"
        disk         = "pd-standard"
        disk_size_gb = 15
        count        = 2
        min          = 0
        max          = 0
      },
      proxy = {
        hw           = "highcpu-8"
        disk         = "pd-standard"
        disk_size_gb = 15
        count        = 0
        min          = 0
        max          = 20
      },
      proxyspot = {
        hw           = "highcpu-8"
        disk         = "pd-standard"
        disk_size_gb = 15
        count        = 1
        min          = 0
        max          = 20
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here are the configs for my testing cluster:

*terraform/clusters/test_madrid_cluster/main.tf*:

```
module "test-madrid-cluster" {
  source       = "../../modules/gke_cluster"
  name         = "test-madrid-cluster"
  location     = "europe-southwest1-a"
  node_pools = var.default_node_pool_configs["pop2"]

  // Pass the default node pool configs to the module
  default_node_pool_configs = var.default_node_pool_configs

}
```

*terraform/clusters/test_madrid_cluster/variables.tf*:

```
variable "default_node_pool_configs" {
  description = "Default node pool configurations for GKE clusters"
  type        = map(any)
}
```

My expectation while running `terraform plan` inside *terraform/clusters/test_madrid_cluster/* was, that the `pop2` values would be used (from default_node_pool_configs map inside *terraform/modules/gke_cluster/variables.tf*).

Instead of that, I am being prompted for the value:

```
❯ terraform plan
var.default_node_pool_configs
  Default node pool configurations for GKE clusters

  Enter a value:
```

How do I fix my reference, so the map's value is assigned properly?